# How to abstractly deserialize different enum types with Jackson based on common field?

Tags: java, json, generics, enums, jackson

#### Problem:

I am deserializing `enum`s with Jackson that don't match up with their name in the code, below is a sample of json.

```
{
    "thing1": {"foo": "cool-guy"},
    "thing2": {"foo": "loser-face"}
}
```

Here is the `enum`, I will explain the `interface` later.

```
enum Foo implements HasText {
    COOL_GUY("cool-guy"), LOSER_FACE("loser-face"), // etc...

    private String text;

    private Foo(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

I know how to solve this issue for each `enum` *individually* by making a deserializer (below) and the annotation `@JsonDeserialize(using = FooDeserializer .class)` on the setter method for foo.

```
public class FooDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Enum<Foo>> {
    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws Exception {

      if (p.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
        String jsonText = p.getText();
        Stream<Foo> stream = Arrays.asList(Foo.values()).stream();
        return stream.filter(a -> a.getText().equals(jsonText.toLowerCase())).findAny().get();
      }

      throw context.mappingException(Foo.class);
    }
}
```

#### Question:

**Is there a way to do this abstractly?** That's why I added the HasText `interface` to all my enums in hopes there was a way to do something like this:

```
public class EnumWithTextDeserializer<T extends Enum<T> & HasText> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws Exception {
        if (p.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
          final String jsonText = p.getText();
          final Stream<T> stream = Arrays.asList(runtimeClass().getEnumConstants()).stream();
          return stream.filter(a -> a.getText().equals(jsonText.toLowerCase())).findAny().get();
        }
        throw context.mappingException(runtimeClass());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Class<T> runtimeClass() {
        ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        return (Class<T>) superclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

The compile won't let me annotate the setter method (`@JsonDeserialize(using = EnumWithTextDeserializer.class)`) with this class though because

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<EnumWithTextDeserializer> to Class<? extends JsonDeserializer<?>>".
```

**Really, all I want to be able to do is deserialize these `enum`s based on the getText() method.**

Comment: What happens if different enums define the same text?

Comment: None of them do, but if they did then ideally it wouldn't be a problem. With the specific deserializer you have a runtime copy of the enum and with the abstract one you should be able to but its difficult. I don't know how to pass the enum as the type argument in the annotation.

Comment: That "type mismatch" error seems weird; can you please confirm that you don't have two jackson libraries in your classpath (codehaus and fasterxml) and you're not accidentally using the wrong imports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deserialize, you can specify your String value using `@JsonValue`.

```
public enum FooEnum implements WithText {
    AWESOME("awesome-rad"),
    NARLY("totally-narly");

    private final String text;

    FooEnum(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonValue
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Then executing this code to serialize/deserialize

```
    ImmutableMap<String, FooEnum> map = ImmutableMap.of("value", FooEnum.AWESOME, "value2", FooEnum.NARLY);
    final String value;
    try {
        value = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    }

    Map<String, FooEnum> read;
    try {
        read = objectMapper.readValue(value, new TypeReference<Map<String, FooEnum>>() {});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
```

I get:

```
read = {LinkedHashMap@4627}  size = 2
  0 = {LinkedHashMap$Entry@4631} "value1" -> "AWESEOME"
  1 = {LinkedHashMap$Entry@4632} "value2" -> "NARLY"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am trying to deserialize, not serialize.

Comment: Ohh whoops, let me see if I can fix

Comment: The answer has been amended to show using ```@JsonValue``` supports both serialization and deserialization in the case of Enums

Comment: This works, thanks. I think the JavaDoc for `@JsonValue` should be updated, it only mentions anything about serializing. Also, I found that this works if the annotation is on the interface!